# NativeScriptException: Corrupted navigation stack

Tags: android, exception, nativescript

I'm creating my first application in NativeScript 1.7.0 (android platform for the moment) and I run into this error that crashes the application from time to time when pressing the back button on certain pages. I'm not sure what the exact conditions for this to occur are.

Has anyone else encountered this before? Any ideas why this could be happening and how to fix or avoid it?

NativeScript 1.7.0
tns-core-modules ^1.7.1
tns-android 1.7.1

Here is the information about the exception that is printed in the console:

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onBackPressed failed

Error: Corrupted navigation stack; page: undefined; currentNavigationPage: undefined
File: "/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js, line: 664, column: 43

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'Frame._processNavigationQueue', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 173, column: 19
    Frame: function:'_completePageAddition', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/transition/transition.js', line: 228, column: 15
    Frame: function:'_onFragmentShown', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/transition/transition.js', line: 197, column: 9
    Frame: function:'onFragmentShown', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 43, column: 22
    Frame: function:'FragmentClass.onCreateView', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 537, column: 13
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onBackPressed', file:'/data/data/com.carteplay.consumer/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 664, column: 44


    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Platform.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Platform.java:816)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:715)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:694)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:684)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onBackPressed(NativeScriptActivity.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2179)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2650)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2424)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(NativeScriptActivity.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1877)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3884)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3867)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3513)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3567)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3624)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3513)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3513)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3752)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2022)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1738)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1729)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1999)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:133)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using Android 1.7.1 or later of both the tns-core-modules and of the platform.  Several versions of NS had some navigation issues.  My understanding is they all should be solved in v1.7.1

To upgrade; change to your main project directory and do each of these simple commands:

- npm install tns-core-modules@latest -s
- tns platform remove android
- tns platform add android

Then you can type a "cat package.json" or "type package.json" and you should see both the platform and core modules at v1.7.1 or greater.

Comment: I am already using tns-core-modules and tns-android version 1.7.1.

In package.json:

    "tns-android": {
      "version": "1.7.1"
    }

    "tns-core-modules": "^1.7.1"

Comment: Hmm, now that is very interesting.  

1. Is this easily duplicated?
2. Would it be possible for you to put the app somewhere for me (or Telerik) to look at so that we can see why it is crashing.